# Como mostrar a versão do projeto na página JSP de uma aplicação Java Web com Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

No projeto Java Web com framework Spring MVC tem o arquivo `pom.xml` e dentro desse arquivo tem várias propriedades, dentre essas propriedade tem a versão do projeto: `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Essa versão do projeto fica dentro do arquivo `pom.xml` mais ou menos assim

### pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.meuprojetojavaweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>MeuProjeto</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MeuProjeto</name>

    ...
</project>
```

E estou precisando mostrar essa versão do projeto diretamente em uma página web `.JSP`, de preferência no rodapé de todas as páginas. De maneiro que fique simalar como no código abaixo:

### index.jsp

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
            <b>Version</b> {project.version}
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright © 2017 <a href="#">MeuProjeto</a>.</strong> Todos os direitos reservados.
    </footer>
    </body>
```

Onde esta o "código" `{project.version}` seria onde vai buscar a versão do projeto que esta registrado no arquivo `pom.xml`.

Por isso peço ajuda aqui, pois não sei como proceder e mostrar a versão do meu projeto.

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo **pom.xml**, adicione a seguinte configuração:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>sistema.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Crie um arquivo de propriedades no diretório src/main/resources  Por exemplo: sistema.properties

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que vocẽ executar a tarefa do Maven, o arquivo será atualizado.

Vocẽ pode acessar os valores do arquivo de propriedades em qualquer lugar do sistema, inclusive de um JSP.